# Why do I see update-like marks in Synaptic Manager (Mint/Xfce) although there is no update available?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, upgrade, thunar, synaptic

I'm in Linux Mint 14, Xfce.

In Synaptic Manager I see these marks that seem to indicate an available upgrade, but there isn't any.

[image]

Update manager finds nothing to upgrade.

For other programs these marks are absent:
[image]

Is there something amiss here?

(Maybe related to the fact that I have upgraded Thunar as shown [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-thunar-with-tabs-support-in.html) which I guess upgraded Xfce too.)

What are these marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you selected is up-to-date, you can only do re-installation as the Synaptic Package Manager suggested.

If your `update manager` is not showing any package to upgrade, try update the package cache, IIRC there's a `Update` button you can click on (or `sudo apt-get update` in CLI). If it still contains nothing, there's no package update available.

Comment: it is clear from the beginning that i'm up to date but i see those marks that look like those for an update. are they the same ones? something like an error? i'll add another screenshot for programs that are installed and do not have that mark, to see the difference

Comment: so, it's a local mystery then... (too localized)

Comment: @cipricus It might happen to someone else, might as well leave it